# Add role to user in Simple Membership ASP NET MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, simplemembership

I am using Simplie MemberShip Provider on my ASP NET MVC 4 App. And have some error when i connect user with role. 
That steps what i do:

1.Add providers on web.config:

```
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="SimpleRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="SimpleRoleProvider" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleRoleProvider, WebMatrix.WebData" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
<membership defaultProvider="SimpleMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="SimpleMembershipProvider" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider, WebMatrix.WebData" />
  </providers>
</membership>
<sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="ContextDataModel" />
  </providers>
</sessionState>
```

2. Initialize DB with next code:

```
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("SomeDataBaseModel", "webpages_Users", "Id", "Name", true);
```

3. Create user:

```
membership.CreateUserAndAccount(user, userPassword);
```

Where `membership` is `SimpleMembershipProvider membership = (SimpleMembershipProvider)Membership.Provider;`

4. Create role:

   `roles.CreateRole(userRole);`

Where `roles` is `SimpleRoleProvider roles = (SimpleRoleProvider)Roles.Provider;`

5. Try connect User with Role:

   `roles.AddUsersToRoles(new[] { user }, new[] { userRole });`

And on this step i have Exception:

```
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "webpages_Roles_webpages_Users_Source". The conflict occurred in database "SomeDataBase", table "dbo.webpages_Roles", column 'RoleId'.
The statement has been terminated.
```

I checked the user and role. They exist. And if i connect them manually, the error does not occur. 
I'm using **MS SQL Server database**.
Any ideas what is going on here? Maybe need more information to understand this error?

**UPD**: `user`, `userPassword` and `userRole` is string constants

**UPD2**: This error occurs if the database contains data. If the database is initially empty, no error occurs in step 5.

Comment: I found the same problems ([Tip1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20139442/error-using-addusertorole-of-simplemembership-insert-statement-conflicted-with)[Tip2](https://forums.asp.net/t/1911290.aspx?SimpleMembership+and+SimpleRoles+provider+Bug)) with other people. And as i can judge only the right decisions there is no. I tried their ways at myself and they didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I corrected this error.

First of all check your **database schema**.

The columns `UserId` and `RoleId` in table `webpages_UsersInRoles` must ordered like that: **First column `UserId`, Second column `RoleId`**. After check table relationships between `webpages_Roles` and `webpages_Users` (this is table that you define for user id, login and another information). They must be correct.

If you use [Code-First Model](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/what-is-code-first.aspx) сheck your model for the correctness of the relationships between these tables.

For me correct model looks like that:

```
public partial class YourContextModel : DbContext
{
    public YourContextModel()
        : base("name=YourDataBaseConnectionString")
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<webpages_Membership> webpages_Membership { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<webpages_OAuthMembership> webpages_OAuthMembership { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<webpages_Roles> webpages_Roles { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<webpages_Users> webpages_Users { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<webpages_Users>()
            .HasOptional(e => e.webpages_Membership)
            .WithRequired(e => e.webpages_Users);

        modelBuilder.Entity<webpages_Users>()
            .HasMany(e => e.webpages_Roles)
            .WithMany(e => e.webpages_Users)
            .Map(m => m.ToTable("webpages_UsersInRoles").MapLeftKey("UserId").MapRightKey("RoleId"));
    }
}
```